# Angle orientation for a binary image

Tags: c#

I'm trying to code a function that calculate an angle orientation for a binary image that contain one object (trying to get the orientation of this object). I calculate the gradient of the image and calculate the angle between the 2 gradient X and Y with this function:

```
double theta = Math.Atan(gradientX_coord/gradientY_coord);
theta = (theta * 180) / Math.PI;
```

after that I normalized the angle by this:

```
angle += angle [i];
angle = angle /gradient.width * gradient.height
```

I don't get the right angle value after what I did. What is wrong with my code?

Help please.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information? What result are you expecting and what do you actually get?

Comment: With `angle = angle /gradient.width * gradient.height` do you actually want `angle = angle / (gradient.width * gradient.height)` ?

Comment: Well, i have a form in a image that i want to rotate. I calculate the angle manually with imageJ to have an inforamtion in what i should have. The probleme that what i should have is not what i really get with my function.

Comment: Yes Batu Zet because my angle is the sum og all angle calulate between the 2 gradient image.

Comment: In the first code block, you should use `Math.Atan2(gradientY_coord,gradientX_coord)` if you expect angles outside [-pi/2,pi/2]. It's not clear at all, what you try to achieve with the second block. What is `gradient.width`?